# Unknown argument: theme in Webpack 2.7.0

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Currently I am using webpack 1.16.0 and passing an argument --theme to define the output path and plugin paths.

the command looks like this: 
`rimraf dist && webpack --bail --progress --profile --theme=<name of theme>`

Now I am trying to upgrade to webpack 2.7.0 and there I face the following issue: Unknown argument: theme

Is there a way to pass the theme with webpack 2.7.0? Does not look like theme is a valid config option. What can I use in place of theme?

Comment: webpack is on version 4 now. You wont get any support, nor people will know about it. I recommend if possible upgrading to v4 or v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by passing --env.theme='' in the command line!